# Reuseability of Hyperledger Fabric components in Hyperledger Indy

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-indy

I want to use some of the features and conponents of Hyperledger Fabric in Hhyperledger Indy? Can I use them?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, no. They are independent blockchain technologies (as are Hyperledger Sawooth or Hyperledger Burrow).  Some of the code may be reusable, but the APIs/SDKs are completely different.

Edit: but you should be able to have an application that uses Hyperledger Indy for identity management and, independently, Hyperledger Fabric (or Sawtooth or Burrow or Iroha) for your ledger data.